# MySQL select from second row where

Tags: mysql

I have three tables containing books and tags. A book can be tagged with several tags.

What I want to do is to filter out books whish are tagged with both 'Comics' AND 'Romance'.

1. The first book is tagged only with 'Comics'.
2. The second book is tagged with both 'Comics' AND 'Romance', so this row should be returned in our example.
3. The third book is tagged only with 'Fantasy'.

How do I construct a proper query to find the second book?

> ..select book_id from books b, tags t, tags_to_books tb where ((FIND
>   TAGS_ID '7' AND '8'))..

Table design:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `books`;
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`)
 );

 INSERT INTO `books` (`book_id`)
 VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tags`;
 CREATE TABLE `tags` (
   `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `tag_name` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`)
 );

 INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_id`, `tag_name`)
 VALUES
(7,'Comics'),
(8,'Romance'),
(9,'Fantasy');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tags_to_books`;
 CREATE TABLE `tags_to_books` (
   `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO `tags_to_books` (`book_id`, `tag_id`)
 VALUES
(1,7),
(2,7),
(2,8),
(3,9);
```

Comment: Nicely asked question.  Just the right amount of detail to let people work on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this, which is effectively the same as an intersection operator in other SQL languages:

```
select comics.book_id from (
select b.book_id
  from books b
  join tags_to_books tb on tb.book_id = b.book_id
  join tags t on tb.tag_id = t.tag_id
  where t.tag_id = 7) as comics
join (
select b.book_id
  from books b
  join tags_to_books tb on tb.book_id = b.book_id
  join tags t on tb.tag_id = t.tag_id
  where t.tag_id = 8) as romance
on comics.book_id = romance.book_id
```

This could probably be optimized a little, but the idea is to get all the books that are in Fantasy and then all the books that are in Romance, and then return the books that are in both.  If you needed to create a query where you needed more criteria, you would just copy the JOIN clause and update the tag id.

[Link to SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc556/15)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the same book can appear in the tag table multiple times. Correct?

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT book_id
FROM books
WHERE book_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT comics.book_id
    FROM tags_to_books as comics
    JOIN tags_to_books as romance
      ON comics.book_id = romance.book_id
    WHERE comics.tag_id = 7
      AND romance.tag_id = 8)
```

?

Comment: I think you got it backwards.  All you need is the inner query - SELECT comics.book_id
    FROM tags_to_books as comics
    JOIN tags_to_books as romance
      ON comics.book_id = romance.book_id
    WHERE comics.tag_id = 7
      AND romance.tag_id = 8  - SQLFiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc556/21

Comment: Wasn't the request to filter **out** the books where it was tagged with both comic and romance?

Comment: "Filter out" was used to basically mean "returns"  Requirement #2 was where the OP said that she just wanted book #2

Comment: This would probably be the fastest solution. As @BrianHoover noted - to get the inverse set of books just remove the outer query.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonny and Brian! I ended up using Jonny's version with Brian's modification in the first comment above. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to read that but:

```
SELECT B.book_id
FROM Books B INNER JOIN tags_to_books ttb
ON ttb.book_ID = b.book_ID
JOIN tags t
ON t.tag_ID = ttb.Tag_ID
WHERE t.tag_ID IN(7) AND t.tag_ID IN(8)
```

I haven't compiled this but it should work

OR as Joe described, you can do this by tag_name

```
SELECT B.book_id
FROM Books B INNER JOIN tags_to_books ttb
ON ttb.book_ID = b.book_ID
JOIN tags t
ON t.tag_ID = ttb.Tag_ID
WHERE t.tag_name = 'Comics' AND t.tag_name = 'Romance'
```

Comment: I think you're nearly there, in that OP probably wants `SELECT B.book_id
FROM Books B INNER JOIN tags_to_books ttb
ON ttb.book_ID = b.book_ID
JOIN tags t
ON t.tag_ID = ttb.Tag_ID
WHERE t.tag_ID IN( SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = 'Comics' OR tag_name = 'Romance')`

Comment: The first query will return both book 1 and book 2 since book 1 is also IN(7,8).  A correct query will only return book 2.

Comment: @Joel My apologies, I did not see that. The OP code was not formatted when I answered so was difficult to read what values were needed!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the `book_id` (rather than, say, the name of the book or the text of the tag, this works (but requires changing the magic number described below if you have a different number of tags in your query):

```
SELECT book_id FROM tags_to_books
WHERE tag_id IN (7, 8)
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT book_id, tag_id) = 2;
```

That `2` is the number of tags, which you'd have to change if there were more or fewer tags in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc556/6 
Hope this helps